# Javascript, how to use !- NOT operator

Tags: javascript

I try to solve Javascript kata at codewars:

*If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Finish the solution so that it returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in. Additionally, if the number is negative, return 0 (for languages that do have them).

Note: If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, only count it once.

Courtesy of projecteuler.net (Problem 1)
*

Can someone please explain me why my code returns false values? I believe it is due to NOT operator.

```
function solution(number){
 let result = 0
 if (number<0)
  return 0
   for (let i=1; i<number; i++){
if ((number-i)%3===0)
  {result = result + (number/3)
  }
}
  for (let j=1; j<number; j++)
    if ((number-j)%5===0 && (!(number-j)%3)===0)
     {result = result + (number/5)
    }
 return result 
 }
```

Comment: I believe you want `(number-j)%3) !== 0` and not cast `(number-j)%3` to boolean _and_ than compare to 0

Comment: Also try writing better formatted code. Now it's huge mess

Comment: Use `!==` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to simplify the code to something like:

```js
function solution(lim) {
  let result = 0
  for (let i = 1; i < lim; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
      result += i
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(
  solution(10)
  ,solution(-1)
  ,solution(0)
)
// 23 0 0
```

...it's easier to test for divisibily by 3 or 5 in one go, rather than twice.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, the ES6 way:

```js
function* range(inc, max) {
  let i=0;
  while((i+=inc)<max) yield i;
}

function solution(n) {
  return n<0?0:[...new Set([...range(3,n),...range(5,n)])].reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
}

console.log(solution(10))
```